# How to get notified if a friend accept my application invitation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml, xfbml

We can able to invite friends for an application,Is any way to get information the particular friend accept my invitation?

Answer (score 0):

generally we provide a link to the "accept button" the moment friend clicks on it, a web browser with the link opens up, and there you can do whatever you like.

but if you are asking for something like "acknowledgment" if the user has read the mail...or so then case is different...

Comment: Can we able to send user specific link/       Like             app_request?sender=123123

Comment: You can use the `data` parameter of the invite dialog to pass specific data.